# CKEditor multiple style class not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I have a custom CMS which using CKEditor. There is a big problem when I am adding multiple classes to a class attribute.

```
<p class="abc xyz">
 //
</p>
```

I am adding like this, but it renders as,

```
<p>
 //
</p>
```

Can I solve this using config.js or something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to go into the config.js and set

```
CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent = true;
```

This way you will stop the CKEditor from stripping off the classes from your elements.

Which version of CKEditor are you using?
If the problem started happening when you updated CKEditor library to 4.1 then in the "Advanced options" section of CKEditor profile add this:

```
config.allowedContent = true;
```

If you still have problem with this please refer to the **[CKEditor API Documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_allowed_content_rules)** which states everything that you will need about this.

Comment: Use `config.extraAllowedContent = 'p(*)';` instead of `allowedContent = true;`! You don't have to disable the entire feature to adjust a simple case.

Comment: Now it's working using second option. config.allowedContent = true;

Comment: This solution may require both (I already had allowedContent set to true) but, specifically, adding the element qualifier oleq describes worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the complete example for **CKEDITOR 4.x** if you don't want to modify the **config.js** file:

**HTML**

```
<textarea name="post_content" id="post_content" class="form-control"></textarea>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
CKEDITOR.replace('post_content', {
   allowedContent:true,
});
```

The above code will allow all tags in the editor.

For more Detail : [**CK EDITOR Allowed Content Rules**](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_allowed_content_rules-section-debugging)